# Ranking NAs in a vector equally [r]

Tags: r, na

I'm wondering if I'm missing something trivial here:

When ranking a vector like this containing NAs, there are four options of how to deal with the NAs:

```
x<-c(5, NA, 3, NA, 6, 9, 10, NA, 5, 7, 12)

rank(x, na.last=T)   
# [1]  2.5  9.0  1.0 10.0  4.0  6.0  7.0 11.0  2.5  5.0  8.0

rank(x, na.last=F)
# [1]  5.5  1.0  4.0  2.0  7.0  9.0 10.0  3.0  5.5  8.0 11.0

rank(x, na.last=NA)
# [1] 2.5 1.0 4.0 6.0 7.0 2.5 5.0 8.0

rank(x, na.last="keep")
#  [1] 2.5  NA 1.0  NA 4.0 6.0 7.0  NA 2.5 5.0 8.0
```

I am looking to keep and rank the NAs.  For my purposes they should be ranked equally and last.  In this situation the `ties.method` to be used is ok to be the default "average".  I'm looking for this result:

```
#  [1] 2.5  10.0 1.0  10.0 4.0 6.0 7.0  10.0 2.5 5.0 8.0
```

From the ?rank help:  "NA values are never considered to be equal: for na.last = TRUE and na.last = FALSE they are given distinct ranks in the order in which they occur in x."

So, it looks like what I want - i.e. to treat them equally and average their rank as a last rank is not possible through using `rank`.   Is this true - is there no simple way of getting this done via rank?     Do I have to rely on a second line of code to re-insert the rank of the NAs after doing  `rank(x, na.last="keep")`  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rank it both forward and backwards and then take the mean:

```
(rank(x, na.last=T) + rev(rank(rev(x), na.last=T))) / 2
# [1]  2.5 10.0  1.0 10.0  4.0  6.0  7.0 10.0  2.5  5.0  8.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is the most elegant solution, but you could replace the NA values so that they are always last, like so:

```
rank( replace(x, is.na(x), max(x,na.rm=TRUE) + 1) )
#[1]  2.5 10.0  1.0 10.0  4.0  6.0  7.0 10.0  2.5  5.0  8.0
```